# export javascript not working for large file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to export data to file.
The export works great for pretty much all files, but when I try to export large datasets it is not working.

any clues?

here is the code

```
a.href = 'data:' + mimeType + ',' + encodeURIComponent(content);
a.setAttribute('download', fileName);
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

Comment: How large is your data set? Also, what do you expect to happen? What actually happens? Are there any console errors?

Comment: no console error, but I managed to solve this using Blob. Thanks!!!

Comment: Would you mind creating an answer to your question about how you solved it and why it wasn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following function. Not sure why it solved the problem. I guess it is a browser thing.

```
download(content, fileName, mimeType) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        mimeType = mimeType || 'application/octet-stream';

        if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE10
            return navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([content], { type: mimeType }),     fileName);
        } else if ('download' in a) { //html5 A[download]
            var csvData = new Blob([content], { type: mimeType });
            var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(csvData);
            //a.href = 'data:' + mimeType + ',' + encodeURIComponent(content);
            a.href = csvUrl;
            a.setAttribute('download', fileName);
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            console.log(a);
            //document.body.removeChild(a);
            /*
            setTimeout(function() {
                a.click();
                console.log(a);
                document.body.removeChild(a);
            }, 66);*/

            return true;
        } else { //do iframe dataURL download (old ch+FF):
            var f = document.createElement('iframe');
            document.body.appendChild(f);
            f.src = 'data:' + mimeType + ',' + encodeURIComponent(content);

            setTimeout(function() {
                document.body.removeChild(f);
            }, 333);
            return true;
        }
    },
```